# Representations and support.

Tags: reference-request, rt.representation-theory

I am interested in the question: Does there are exist concept of support in representation theory?

When I say support I mean number of non-zero values of $f \in C[G]$.
Do you know theorems which talks about the action of elements of $C[G]$ with small support in different representations?

The only example I know about is uncertainty principle which says that for abelian group $supp(f)supp(\hat{f})\geq |A|$.

Comment: I think the question would benefit from being slightly more precise. It seems better to me if one asks for "theorems that show something like X happens" rather than "theorems which use the concept X".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although perhaps the question was directed more at finite groups: for reductive or semi-simple real Lie groups, (serious) results of Harish-Chandra (starting in the early 1950s) show that among regular semi-simple elements of the group, the supports of characters of principal series are the smallest, being confined to (maximally) *split* conjugacy classes, while at the opposite end the characters of discrete series have non-trivial support on *all* semi-simple conjugacy classes. The in-between repns, i.e., induced from discrete series on Levis, have in-between supports, in terms of split-ness.

I have the impression that suitable analogues hold for p-adic reductive groups, tho' the corresponding results are relatively much-newer (by a displacement of 15-20 years?), not to mention the complication in description of discrete series (supercuspidal repns) as induced from compact-open subgroups (Kutzko-Bushnell-et-alia). Early computations for the p-adic case go back to MacDonald (SL2) in the 1950s, and Shalika, Sally in the 1960s (SL2), Jacquet in the late 1960s, so far as I know.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you, please, give me a reference where I can read about this results?  

Comment: Knapp's "Repn theory of semi-simple groups" is an extensive introduction, with huge biblio and historical notes, for the Lie case. AMS Proc Symp Pure Math 61, from Durham Conference. On-line, among many others, papers at the atlas-of-Lie groups site, http://www.liegroups.org/papers/. Also the Langlands archive at IAS, the Arthur archive at Clay, and Casselman's archive at UBC. The p-adic business is currently very active, so googling will find many "live" things.